# Skip Inno Setup custom page, unless specific radio button is selected on previous page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have code which is used for custom installation using Inno Setup. In this I have two radio buttons on a custom page. If user selects the first radio button, it should show another custom page with user input text box and text to be save in file. If user select the other radio button, the other custom page should not show.

Here is my code

```pascal
[Code]
var
  FullRadioButton: TNewRadioButton;
  PartRadioButton: TNewRadioButton;
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;
  UserInputsPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  FullDescLabel: TLabel;
  PartDescLabel: TLabel;
  url: String;

const
  FullDescText ='Full Installation.';
  PartDescText ='Partial Installation.';

procedure InitializeWizard; 
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Installation type', '');
  FullRadioButton := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  FullRadioButton.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  FullRadioButton.Top := 16;
  FullRadioButton.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  FullRadioButton.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  FullRadioButton.Font.Size := 9;
  FullRadioButton.Caption := 'Default Installation'
  FullDescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  FullDescLabel.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  FullRadioButton.Checked := True;
  FullDescLabel.Left := 8;
  FullDescLabel.Top := FullRadioButton.Top + FullRadioButton.Height + 8;
  FullDescLabel.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth; 
  FullDescLabel.Height := 40;
  FullDescLabel.AutoSize := False;
  FullDescLabel.Wordwrap := True;
  FullDescLabel.Caption := FullDescText;
  PartRadioButton := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  PartRadioButton.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  //PartRadioButton.Checked := True
  PartRadioButton.Top := FullDescLabel.Top + FullDescLabel.Height + 16;
  PartRadioButton.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  PartRadioButton.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  PartRadioButton.Font.Size := 9;
  PartRadioButton.Caption := 'Custom Installation'
  PartDescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  PartDescLabel.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  PartDescLabel.Left := 8;
  PartDescLabel.Top := PartRadioButton.Top + PartRadioButton.Height + 8;
  PartDescLabel.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  PartDescLabel.Height := 40;
  PartDescLabel.AutoSize := False;
  PartDescLabel.Wordwrap := True;
  PartDescLabel.Caption := PartDescText;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
if (PartRadioButton.Checked) then
    UserInputsPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
          'Url information', 'Url',
          'Please specify the following informat, then click Next.');
    
    UserInputsPage.Add('URL:', False);
    UserInputsPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('');
  if(CurPageID = UserInputsPage.ID) then;
  begin
    url := UserInputsPage.Values[0];
    SaveStringToFile('path', 'user_input='+'"'+url+'"'+#13#10,True);
  end;
 Result := True;
end;
```

Please help me out
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TWizardPage.OnShouldSkipPage` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardPage) (or [`ShouldSkipPage` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage)) to conditionally skip your custom page.

The custom page should better also be created (unconditionally) in the `InitializeWizard`, not in the `NextButtonClick` (the `NextButtonClick` can be called multiple times for the same page, if the user returns back).

Additionally, the `UserInputsPage` must show after the `CustomPage`. While you are currently constructing it to show before. For that, pass `CustomPage.ID` as the first argument of the `CreateInputQueryPage`.

```pascal
function UserInputsPageShouldSkipPage(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not PartRadioButton.Checked;
end;
```

```pascal
UserInputsPage :=
  CreateInputQueryPage(
    CustomPage.ID, 'Url information', 'Url',
    'Please specify the following informat, then click Next.');
// ...
UserInputsPage.OnShouldSkipPage := @UserInputsPageShouldSkipPage;
```

Similar questions:

- [How to skip custom page based on setup type in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58559285/850848)
- [Skipping custom pages based on optional components in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13921535/850848)

---

Also, you should not do any changes to the user's system, before the user confirms the installation. So typically, you do not want call `SaveStringToFile` when user click *Next* on the custom page (not to mention again that it can happen multiple times, if user returns back). Better use [`CurStepChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) for `ssInstall` or `ssPostInstall` step.

And your `NextButtonClick` code is wrong anyway, due to the semicolon after the `then`. Effectively you call `SaveStringToFile` on each and every page of the wizard.